# How to programatically import a user from LDAP Liferay 6.0.5

Tags: ldap, liferay-6

I would like to import a user programatically from LDAP to Liferay 6.0.5.

Are there any suggestions or samples plz.

Advance thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check liferay's source code in **com.liferay.portal.security.ldap.PortalLDAPImporterImpl**, this may give you better idea regarding how to do it in liferay.

or

you can try the following code in your custom portlet, the code is very basic (I have removed and kept only the basics which would be required so it will **not compile** but still with very little modification it should work):

```
import javax.naming.CommunicationException;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NameClassPair;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;

import com.liferay.portal.model.User;

public class MyProgramaticLDAP {

    private static final Properties ENV_PROPS = new Properties();

    static {
        ENV_PROPS.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        ENV_PROPS.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://url.to.my.com:389");
        ENV_PROPS.setProperty(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "uid=myuserid,ou=people,dc=myorg,dc=com");
        ENV_PROPS.setProperty(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "mypassword");
        ENV_PROPS.setProperty("PROVIDER_PROTOCOL", "ldap"));
        ENV_PROPS.setProperty("PROVIDER_PORT", "389");
        ENV_PROPS.setProperty("PROVIDER_HOST", "192.168.5.234");
        ENV_PROPS.setProperty("LDAP_BASE_URL", "ldap://url.to.my.com:389");
        ENV_PROPS.setProperty("CONTEXT_NAME", "ou=people,dc=myorg,dc=com"));
    }

    public User getLdapUser(String userEmail) throws PortalException,
            SystemException, WebServiceAuthenticationException {

        DirContext ctx = null;
        String userContext = StringPool.BLANK;
        String userName = null;
        NamingEnumeration results = null;

        //liferay user
        User user = new User(); //won't compile

        try {
            // context and specifying LDAP service provider parameters.
            ctx = new InitialDirContext(ENV_PROPS);

            userContext = "uid=" + userEmail + "," + ENV_PROPS.getProperty("CONTEXT_NAME");
            results = ctx.list(ENV_PROPS.getProperty("CONTEXT_NAME"));

            System.out.println("User context: " + userContext);

            Attributes attrs = null;

            while (results.hasMore()) {

                NameClassPair ncp = (NameClassPair) results.next();

                userName = ncp.getName();

                // the attributes for the record retrieved, your attributes may differ based upon the LDAP you use
                System.out.println("Fetching attributes");

                attrs = ctx.getAttributes(userName + "," + ENV_PROPS.getProperty("CONTEXT_NAME"));

                System.out.println("Attribute mail: " + attrs.get("mail").get());           
                System.out.println("Attribute sn: " + attrs.get("sn").get());
                System.out.println("Attribute title: " + attrs.get("title").get());
                System.out.println("Attribute mobile: " + attrs.get("mobile").get());

                System.out.println("Attribute firstname: " + attrs.get("firstname").get());
                user.setFirstName(attrs.get("firstname").get());

                System.out.println("Attribute department: " + attrs.get("department").get());

            }// while ends here

        } catch (CommunicationException cex) {
            cex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStacktrace();
        } finally {
            // close connection and other code
        }

        return user;
    }
}
```